# Is Context compatible with "complex" objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm using React js and Context.
I have a "complex" object like below, which I want to make it available in childs views using Context:

```
{
  carSelected:
  { 
    "carEntityId": 6,
      "mileage": 100000,
      "immatriculationDate": "2020-05-01T00:00:00",
      "vin": "VIN-cF95ew0cp0ZhxE=w",
      "licencePlate": "GR-999-RT"
      "carModel": {
          "carModelId": 2,
          "brand": "Fiat",
          "model": "Tipo",
          "motor": "1.7D",
          ...
      }
  }
  carsAvailable: [
    { 
      <list of car like car selected>
    }
  ]

}
```

In App.js, I'm setting state for that:

```
this.setCarEntity = (carSelected, carsAvailable) => {
   console.info("[setCarEntity] Car selected: " + JSON.stringify(carSelected, null, 4));

   this.setState({
      carEntity: {
          carSelected: carSelected,
          carsAvailable: carsAvailable,
      }
   })
}
```

And then in App render:

```
<CarEntityContext.Provider value={this.state.carEntity}>
   <CarEntityHome/>
</CarEntityContext.Provider>
```

Looks fine to me.

In CarEntityHome, I'm trying to access to the object.
I can access values to primary key, this is working:

```
 <CarEntityContext.Consumer>
     {valueCE => 
         (valueCE !== null && valueCE.carSelected !== null) &&
         <p> Car selected | id {valueCE.carSelected.carEntityId} / {valueCE.carSelected.mileage} km <br/>
        </p>
     }
</CarEntityContext.Consumer>
```

But, I can't access to the object embedded in my "carSelected" object:
`{valueCE.carSelected.carModel.carModelId}`
This is failing, saying:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'carModelId' of undefined`
Same goes for all property in "carModel" subobject.

But, if I display the object to check if it's correctly populated, it is actually the case:

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(valueCE.carSelected, null, 2) }</pre>
```

Give:

```
{
  "carEntityId": 6,
  "mileage": 100000,
  "immatriculationDate": "2020-05-01T00:00:00",
  "vin": "VIN-cF95ew0cp0ZhxE=w",
  "licencePlate": "GR-999-RT",
  "carModel": {
    "carModelId": 2,
    "brand": "Fiat",
    "model": "Tipo",
    "motor": "1.7D",
    "horsePower": 57,
    "kwPower": 40,
    "fiscalPower": 4,
    "energy": "petrol",
    "finition": "Pop",
    "maintenancePlan": null
  },
  "userDB": null
}
```

So I'm very confused here. My object is properly populated. But is there a limitation in Context to access to embedded / complex object ? 
Am I missing something obvious here ?
Could not find an answer in official doc, could be a bug ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.